# What is the meaning of ms-lim?

Tags: limits

I came across an expression as follows:

$$I^{(\alpha)} = ms-\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_n^{(\alpha)}(t)$$

What does this "ms-lim" mean?

**Edit 1:**

Thanks for all the comments. "ms-lim" indeed means "mean-square limit".

Comment: Where did you encounter this? What does it describe?

Comment: It's almost certainly a limit subtracted from a product $ms$, but the original context may prove I'm wrong.

Comment: Apparently it means "mean-square limit": https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/mean-square-convergence

Comment: Similar notation appears [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Applied_Stochastic_Processes_and_Control/gStuMDplR3YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=mean%20square%20limit%20notation&pg=PA37&printsec=frontcover) as $\displaystyle \stackrel{\mathrm{ms}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, ms stands for mean-square.